# How to center the location of the z-axis label?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to center the location of the z-axis label which is `|f(x,t)|`?

[image]

```
 f = Tan[x - t];
Plot3D[Abs[f], {x, -2, 2}, {t, -2, 2}, ViewPoint -> {3.3, -2.4, 2.1}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Business", PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, t, Rotate["|f(x,t)|", 90 Degree]}]
```

Comment: What about the option: `AxesOrigin->{0,0,0}`?

Comment: I think I was misunderstood. I want to center the location of the name of the z- axis label which is `|f(x,t)|`.

Comment: You can sort of fake it by adding spaces to the end of the label

Comment: As @mikado suggested, but use `Spacer` for easier control: `AxesLabel -> {x, t, 
  Rotate[Row[{"|f(x,\[ThinSpace]t)|", Spacer[100]}], 90 Degree]}}`